# Python Pandas calculate funnel

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot

Working with the python pandas dataframe df:

```
Customer_ID | Transaction_ID  | Item_ID | date        | trans_nr
ABC           2017-04-12-333    X8973     2017-04-12     1
ABC           2017-04-12-333    X2468     2017-04-12     1
ABC           2017-05-22-658    X2906     2017-05-22     2
ABC           2017-05-22-757    X8790     2017-05-22     2
ABC           2017-07-13-864    X8790     2017-07-13     3
BCD           2017-08-11-879    X2346     2017-08-11     1
BCD           2017-08-11-879    X2468     2017-08-11     1
CDE           2017-03-05-879    X8973     2017-03-05     1
CDE           2017-05-22-879    X2468     2017-05-22     2
CDE           2017-10-15-879    X2346     2017-10-15     3
```

I need to basically pivot it, to create the item funnel - in other words, understand how many people bought each item in each visit and which item they bought next.

This is the output I am looking for:

```
item_1trans|count_customer|item_2trans|count_customer|item_3trans|count_customer
X8973          2            X2906            1          X8790           1
                            X8790            1          X8790           1
                            X2468            1          X2346           1
X2468          2            X2906            1          X8790           1
                            X8790            1          X8790           1
X2346          1
```

I manage to accomplish this with some ugly code:

```
df_first = df.loc[df['trans_nr'] == 1].copy()
df_first = df_first.rename(columns={'Item_ID': 'item_1trans'})

df_second = df.loc[df['trans_nr'] == 1].copy()
df_second = df_second.rename(columns={'Item_ID': 'item_2trans'})

df_third = df.loc[df['trans_nr'] == 1].copy()
df_third = df_third.rename(columns={'Item_ID': 'item_3trans'})

df_step1 = pd.merge(df_first,df_second,how='outer',on=['Customer_ID'])
df_final = pd.merge(df_step1,df_third,how='outer',on=['Customer_ID'])

pd.pivot_table(df_final,index= \
['item_1trans','item_2trans','item_3trans'],values=["Customer_ID"],\
aggfunc=lambda x: len(x.unique())).to_csv('test.csv')
```

But there has to be a smoother way.